# adding a icon to home screen for a contact to facetime

Tags: iphone, ipad, facetime

I want to add a icon to iPad/iPhone homescreen such that on clicking on it results in a contact's facetime call initiation.

the closest I could come up with is a facetime url as a bookmark which on click initiates a call something like

```
facetime://9999999999
```

however it sits on a browser bookmarks bar.

Answer (score 1):

How much would that feature be worth to you?

[FaceDialer](http://www.eidac.de/?p=192), which I stumbled on while attempting to download smcFanControl, claims to be able to create those links, but is a paid app.